# Extend the properties of datagridview and its cell

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on the datagridview now days. And I have to assign some custom properties to the datagridview which I am able to do. problem comes when I want to extend the properties of the cell. for example I already have my custom textbox control which user can set the behaviour like if its numeric or alphanumeric, allow negative, allow decimals etc etc. which works fine. Now I want to include that textbox control in my extended grid. So user can set all those properties while adding columns.

First of all is it possible? If yes then any tutorial or help please.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully certain so you may want to keep looking, but as far as I know you have to manually set each property of the text box to what you want. There isn't a copy all cell style settings to textbox call you can make.

```
Public Sub funwithDGVs()
    Dim DataGridView1 As New DataGridView
    Dim DataGridViewCell1 As DataGridViewCell

    DataGridViewCell1.ForeColor = Color.Aquamarine
    DataGridView1.Item(0, 1).Style.ForeColor = DataGridViewCell1.ForeColor
    TextBox1.ForeColor = DataGridViewCell1.ForeColor

End Sub
```